# Set connection parameters in RedisConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have simple `Redis` client based on `Spring` below. As default it connects to local host, but I need to set different host and port.

I suppose I can do it in function below:

```
@Bean
RedisMessageListenerContainer container(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    //LettuceConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new PatternTopic("chat"));

    return container;
}
```

I found that I class name of `connectionFactory` is `LettuceConnectionFactory` and it has private field `client` that contains connection information.

What is correct way to change default connection parameters in `RedisConnectionFactory`?

Whole code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MessagingRedisApplication {

    private static final Logger lg = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessagingRedisApplication.class);

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        LettuceConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
        lg.info( connectionFactory.toString() );
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new PatternTopic("chat"));

        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }

    @Bean
    StringRedisTemplate template(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MessagingRedisApplication.class, args);

        StringRedisTemplate template = ctx.getBean(StringRedisTemplate.class);

        Receiver receiver = ctx.getBean(Receiver.class);

        while (receiver.getCount() == 0) {

            lg.info("Sending message...");

            template.convertAndSend("chat", "Hello from Redis!");
            Thread.sleep(500L);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use default spring provided properties to configure your redis connections. For host and port, the followging properties should be enough.

```
spring.redis.host=redis.yourhost.com
spring.redis.port=6379
```

Then the `connectionfactory` bean will created with the given host and port. The whole set of properties are available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data-properties). Search with `spring.redis.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure host name programatically instead of using `spring.redis` properties you can create your own `RedisConnectionFactory` and pass [`RedisConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.0.M3/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisConfiguration.html) to it's constructor :

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("myHostName");
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration);
}
```

In this case I assume you are using single node instance so [`RedisStandaloneConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisStandaloneConfiguration.html) is used.

Comment: why did you made a bean of it? Why without bean, connection is not being set in redis template?